# Browser level load testing

Tags: performance, browser, jmeter

We are planning to do load testing in browser so would like to know if you suggest any tools to achieve the 10k+ load requests.

Also would like to know if it can be achieved through jmeter for browser test.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Yes, this is possible using Jmeter. Go through the [LINK](https://jmeter.apache.org/) and you will find the way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter per se works on [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) level, however given you [properly configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) from the application under test perspective it will be no difference at all, it wouldn't recognise whether it's being hit by JMeter with 10k of virtual users or 10k real browsers.

The most problematic point of using real browsers is an immense amount of hardware you will need for the test, if you look at [Firefox 71 browser requirements](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/77.0.1/system-requirements/) you will see that for normal operation of browser you will need a CPU core and 2 GB of RAM so for 10k real browsers you will need 10K processors and 20 terabytes of RAM.

If you still want to proceed with real browsers be aware that JMeter can be integrated with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) but most probably you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)